# query based on matching elements in DBRef list for mongodb using spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, dbref

I am pretty new to mongodb. I am using spring-data-mongodb for my queries from java. Please guide me if this is achievable.

Say I have two objects "Car" and "User" as following, where car has list of users,

```
Class Car {

    @Id
    String id;
    String model;
    @DBRef
    List<User> users;
    @DBRef
    Company company;

}

Class User {

    @Id
    String id;
    String name;

}
```

I want to find all cars for a user, (find all cars where car.users has given user)

Is it possible to achieve using spring-data-mongodb?

It's pretty easy if there was only one DBRef element, eg, for company I can write a query like this,

```
new Query(Criteria.where("company.$id").is(new ObjectId(companyId)))
```

But, how to achieve this if there is a list of elements referenced as DBRef??

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Querying for one element on an array is exactly like query for a field equality. You could read the MongoDB documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#arrays). So your query will be:

```
new Query(Criteria.where("users.$id").is(new ObjectId(userId)))
```

Comment: Hi @Miguel, What if  i want to search using user's name instead of user id in single query

Comment: been looking for the answer for days now @Sachin. did you find it by any chance? everyone seems to refer to Id,

Comment: @Miguel how to use this with rest api.
should I add a new customRepository and use mongoOperation ?

Answer (score 9):

in repository interface type this query on the method:

```
@Query("{'company' :{'$ref' : 'company' , '$id' : ?0}}")
Company find(String companyId);
```

Comment: If we need to search based on companyId and carId both together

Comment: this query does not work if we need to search on the basis of company name, can someone please help in that case?